# Rails Zoho configuration sending mails via console but not from mailer class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, zoho

I have following smtp configuration on my development.rb

```
   ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
        :address              => "smtp.zoho.com",
        :port                 => 465,
        :user_name => "xxx@xxx.com",
        :password => "xxxx",
        :authentication       => :login,
        :ssl                  => true,
        :tls                  => true,
        :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }
```

I works when I send via rails console , but gives error of

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
):
```

when I send via mailer class.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like gmail is blocking you temporarily while you are trying to reach through controller.

Kindly have a check with this link

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636342470835359266-2568809045&rd=1#cantsignin

Hope this helps.